# Not able to establish a connection between Spring Integration with ActiveMQ using AMQP

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-amqp

while connecting Spring Integration with ActiveMQ using AMQP, getting an error at the time of creating JMSConnectionFactory.

Exception is below.

**org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer - Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'ABM' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=10000, currentAttempts=49, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: Could not create Transport. Reason: java.io.IOException: Transport scheme NOT recognized: [amqp]**

It is working fine with the TCP url but it's not working with AMQP.

How can I establish a connection with Spring Integration with ActiveMQ using AMQP?

Comment: This question is probably more for ActiveMQ by itself. There is just nothing what Spring does something specific for JMS. And I believe the AMQP is not a JMS protocol. You probably need to use a Qpid client with its JMS wrapper around an AMQP 1.0: https://qpid.apache.org/components/jms/index.html. Plus also this one: https://activemq.apache.org/amqp